# how to get value from webbrowser with same classname in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How can I get the specific innertext value of this one? Assuming the value of span class under `<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">`is `<span>Street</span>` then get the value of `<div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-6 right">`

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YPfk.png)

My current code right now

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        If Element.GetAttribute("className") = "row item" And Element.GetAttribute("className") = "col-sm-4 col-xs-6" And Element.GetAttribute("className") = "col-sm-8 col-xs-6 right" Then
            For Each Element1 As HtmlElement In Element.GetElementsByTagName("div")
                If Element1.GetAttribute("className") = "col-sm-8 col-xs-6 right" Then
                    Dim Variable1 As String = Element1.InnerText
                    TextBox1.Text = Variable1
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: There are multiple ways, the most flexible one would be with htmlagilitypack in my opinion (check out my answers on it). I need to see whole html to give an exact answer but you would do it with dim mytext as string = document.selectsinglenode("//div[@class='col-sm-8 col-xs-6']").innertext.

Comment: That you are doing is one of valid ways, but, in several cases string searches fails if inside of those have blank spaces. So, (as advice) replace spaces then do the comparison (eg.: String1.Replace(“ ”, “”) = String2.Replace(“ ”, “”))